# calling signed applet function from javascript with java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

Tags: java, javascript, applet, accesscontrolexception

everyone!

I have a signed applet (named result in html) with a simple function as below:

```
    public  void killApplet() 
    {   
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>(){
           //@Override
           public Object run() {
           // kill the JVM
           System.exit(0); // or any other line here
           String str = "any string";
           return null;
        }
    }); 
    }
```

The Java script code is like:

```
    function exec_java() {
        document.result.killApplet();
    }
```

When I click the button to execute the java function:

```
<button type="button" id="buttontest" onclick="exec_java()">test</button>
```

It shows up an exception as below:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

(java.io.FilePermission C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin read)
```

I am using Windows XP with IE version as below:

IE 7

Vision: 7.0.5730.13

Any expert and give me a clue how to make this exception gone?
Additionally, the weird thing here is I can call a simple function without problem like below:

```
       public int getNumberOfLines(){
            return number_of_lines;
       }
```

Any help would be appreciated! 
PS: Can't post any images cos apparently I am 'new'!
Does anyone have a working sample using?

```
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>()
```

Thanks!

Wu Bi

Answer (score 0):

```
// kill the JVM
System.exit(0);
```

An applet is a guest in a web page that might host other applets.  Calling `System.exit(n)` is like the guest burning down the guest-house.  *Don't do that!*  As such, even a trusted applet is not allowed to invoke the method.

A better way to end an applet is to call:

```
showDocument(thanksForUsingOurAppletURL);
```

Comment: Really thanks for answering my question so soon! my point is not "System.exit(0);" this line. Instead I change it to any other function, like "string a = 'any thing';", I still have another exception as "object doesn't support this property or method." I have been trying to read almost everything on web. Anybody can really help me out here?